# Lists in C++, Overloading methods?

Tags: c++, list, overloading

Good evening guys, I'm totally new to C++ and I've been having some troubles with it.

Now, I'm trying to make a List, after a lot of undos and corrections, I found this error that I cannot solve.

```
#define MAXLIST 100
template <typename T>

class List {
 private:
int maxList;
int last = 0;
T* List;
 public:
List();
explicit List(int tam);
bool listIsFull();
void destroyList();

List<T>() {
last = -1;
maxList = MAXLIST;
list = new T[maxList];
}

List<T>(int tam) {
last = -1;
maxList = tam;
list = new T[maxList];
}


void destroyList() {
last = -1;
}

bool listIsFull() {
if(last == MAXLIST -1)
    return true;
else
    return false;
    }
}
```

Both methods destroyList() and listIsFull(), in my IDE show an error like: 'Cannot be overloaded' 
And both constructors show an error like: 'Does not name a type'

What is that, that i'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This does not appear to be the real code. Post a real (meaning, it compiles except for the noted error) but minimal example. please

Comment: Tip: You can use free tool such as **AStyle** to format the code before posting. Many programmers' editors also provide automatic formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your code appeared to me, you tried to prototype your class and then provide implementation below it, I simply added correct scope and template operators.

```
#define MAXLIST 100

template <typename T>
class List {
private:
    int maxList;
    int last = 0;
    T* List;
public:
    List();
    explicit List(int tam);
    bool listIsFull();
    void destroyList();
};

template<typename T>
List<T>::List<T>() {
    last = -1;
    maxList = MAXLIST;
    list = new T[maxList];
}

template<typename T>
List<T>::List<T>(int tam) {
    last = -1;
    maxList = tam;
    list = new T[maxList];
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::destroyList() {
    last = -1;
}

template<typename T>
bool List<T>::listIsFull() {
    if (last == MAXLIST - 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```